# Laravel: Checking if user has permission

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I'm writing a server based solution. In database there are many users with different permissions and I have to check if they have permission to access module they are trying to.

In every Controller I have included something like:

```
protected $module = "moduleName";
```

I tried to solve it like:

```
function __construct()
{
    $perm = session()->get('perm');
    if (!isset($perm[$this->module]) || !$perm[$this->module]) {
        Session::flash('message_error', "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign'></span> Access denined!");
        return back();
    }
}
```

It shows the message but it still displays the page not redirects back.

As you see I'm reading permissions from session and modules name is saved in controller so I don't think this could be solved by middleware unless I'm making middleware for each module (I'm talking about 30 modules).

Thanks for taking the time to read this

Comment: `return redirect()->back()` ?

Comment: return back() works the same, I'm asking for a different approach

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/back-vs-redirect-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware actually solved this.
Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'module:moduleName'], function () {
    // Routes...
});
```

Custom middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $module)
{
    $perm = session()->get('perm');
    if (!isset($perm[$module]) || !$perm[$module]) {
        Session::flash('message_error', "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign'></span> Access denined!");
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Also I'll mention that Route groups can be nested. So you can wrap multiple groups with something like auth middleware as well

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy fix to your code, you forgot the define the `redirect`, so instead of using

```
return back();
```

use

```
return redirect()->back();
```

This will do the redirect.

There is also a mistake in your reasoning, you could and probably should use middleware.

Middleware does have access to the user, session and can be passed parameters. These are the necessary requirements for your system.

You can also [assign middleware on a controller basis](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#controller-middleware).

Comment: I solved it with middleware. Also return back() == return redirect->back()